# Importando 'LoadingController' no ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

Atualizei meu ionic da versão 2 para a versão 3, e alguns plugins como 'LoadingController' e o "Platform" pararam de funcionar, gerando o erro 
Cannot find name 'LoadingController'.

Não encontrei na doc como importar eles agora.

Segue meu código:

```
import { LoadingController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [ ProfileService, AlertService ]
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, 
  public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
  private loginService: LoginService, 
  private profileService: ProfileService,
  private _alertService: AlertService,
  private platform: Platform ) {
     router.events.subscribe((data) => {
        this.path = data.url.substr(1);
     })

  this.getUserName();
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
     this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
         history.go(-1)
     });
  });  
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os `imports` continuam da mesma forma, mas creio que seja necessário você atualizar essas bibliotecas também. De uma olhada no seu `package.json` e verifique a versão delas.